# Compiling react app using webpack not compiling files as expected

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I would compile using webpack ts files.

In webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = async (env, options) => {
  const dev = options.mode === "development";
  const config = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: {
      polyfill: ["core-js/stable", "regenerator-runtime/runtime"],
      vendor: ["react", "react-dom", "core-js", "@fluentui/react"],
      taskpane: ["react-hot-loader/patch", "./src/taskpane/index.tsx", "./src/taskpane/taskpane.html"],
      commands: "./src/commands/commands.ts",
      loginfile: "./src/login/loginfile.ts",
      logoutfile: "./src/logout/logoutfile.ts",
    },
    output: {
      clean: true,
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".html", ".js"],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
        },
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: ["@babel/preset-typescript"],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: ["react-hot-loader/webpack", "ts-loader"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: "html-loader",
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
          type: "asset/resource",
          generator: {
            filename: "assets/[name][ext][query]",
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new DotenvWebpackPlugin({ path: `.env.${options.mode}` }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            from: "assets/*",
            to: "assets/[name][ext][query]",
          },
          {
            from: "manifest*.json",
            to: "[name]" + "[ext]",
            transform(content) {
              if (dev) {
                return content;
              } else {
                return content.toString().replace(new RegExp(urlDev, "g"), urlProd);
              }
            },
          },
        ],
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "taskpane.html",
        template: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.html",
        chunks: ["taskpane", "vendor", "polyfills"],
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "loginfile.html",
        template: "./src/login/loginfile.html",
        chunks: ["loginfile"],
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "logoutfile.html",
        template: "./src/logout/logoutfile.html",
        chunks: ["logoutfile"],
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "endlogout.html",
        template: "./src/taskpane/endlogout.html",
        chunks: ["login", "vendor", "polyfills"],
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "commands.html",
        template: "./src/commands/commands.html",
        chunks: ["commands"],
      }),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        Promise: ["es6-promise", "Promise"],
      }),
    ],
    devServer: {
      hot: true,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
      server: {
        type: "https",
        options: env.WEBPACK_BUILD || options.https !== undefined ? options.https : await getHttpsOptions(),
      },
      port: process.env.npm_package_config_dev_server_port || 3000,
    },
  };

  return config;
};
```

When I run npm run server I get this issue

> ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:   Module not found: Error:
> Can't resolve '../loginfile.js' in
> '/Users/******/*****/summarizr2/summarizr/src/login'
> ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> '../loginfile.js' in
> '/Users/*****/*****/summarizr2/summarizr/src/login'

samething with logoutfile

I html file I have this code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />

    <!-- Office JavaScript API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../loginfile.js"></script>
</head>
```

I have also tried using `<script type="text/javascript" src="./loginfile.js"></script>` and `src="loginfile.ts"`

Here's my project structure

```
 ├ src
 │  ├ commands
 │  │  ├ commands.html
 │  │  ├ commands.ts
 │  ├ constants
 │  │  ├ authentication.ts
 │  ├ login
 │  │  ├ loginfile.html
 │  │  ├ loginfile.ts
 │  ├ logout
 │  │  ├ logoutfile.html
 │  │  ├ logoutfile.ts
 │  ├ services
 │  │  ├ commands
 │  │  ├ common
 │  ├ taskpane
 │  │  ├ components
 │  │  ├ endlogout.html
 │  │  ├ index.css
 │  │  ├ index.tsx
 │  │  ├ login.html
 │  │  ├ logoutcomplete
 │  │  ├ taskpane.html
 │  │  ├ urls.ts
 ├ tailwind.config.js
 ├ tsconfig.json
 └ webpack.config.js
```

What could be the issue in this case ?

To simplify the question :

I have a test.ts file and test.html file in src/test folder

inside test.html file I have :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />

    <script type="text/javascript" defer src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

I get error

- ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './test.js' in '/Users/*****/****/summarizr2/summarizr/src/test'

But for me test.js should be found in dist folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little vague about whether the HTML you posted is the template or the actual output HTML as inspected in `dist` or in the DOM, so this is based on a bit of an assumption about that being the actual template contents.

The point of `html-webpack-plugin` is to allow Webpack to *generate* the HTML, including the `<script>` lines pointing to your chunk. Where in your template file, it looks like you are trying to hand craft the `<script>` tag that loads the chunk.

By default, with no `template` provided, `HtmlWebpackPlugin` will generate a generic HTML file with the `script` tag automatically injected.

I can see though you actually do need the `template` feature as you are adding an additional script tag that Webpack would otherwise have no context for.

In that template, you will add your additional Office for JS script, but you *will not add any script tag for the chunk*. `HtmlWebpackPlugin` injects that for you in the outputted HTML files inside of `dist` and also those served by the dev server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />

    <!-- Office JavaScript API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
   
    <!-- Webpack Scripts will be auto injected here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What I do not understand is how webpack know that loginfile.js should be injected in loginfile.html ?

Comment: Because you already provided that info to `HtmlWebpackPlugin` via the the `filename`and `chunks` option keys which together are saying "use these chunks for this html filename you will generate". The chunk config option (which tbh is poorly documented) seems to be a reference to the `entry` config object, which has the actual paths to the ts files. Well, loosely anyway, webpack just generated chunk names same as the entry name. Webpack knows the output format of those chunks will be JS. Together that is the info it needs.

Comment: Thank you , I understand better . It's working.
I wanted to do like in this repo https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples/blob/main/Samples/auth/Office-Add-in-Microsoft-Graph-React/login/login.html. , Here in login.html , they are adding `login.js` in `script` tag

Answer (score 0):

Your login.js is a js module

`<script type="module" src="../loginfile.js"></script>`

Comment: That's not resolving the issue

Comment: So what the error says ls it can't resolve module. probably somethings going on with imports... Can you share loginfile.js